# How to get the output of `date` command in a char array?

Tags: c, linux

I want to put the output of GNU/Linux `date` command in a character array.

Example:

```
char array[25];
```

```
$ date
Thu Jul 19 09:21:31 IST 2012
```

```
printf("%s", array);
/* Should display "Thu Jul 19 09:21:31 IST 2012" */
```

I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 50

int main()
{
    char array[SIZE];

    sprintf(array, "%s", system("date"));
    printf("\nGot this: %s\n", array);

    return 0;
}
```

But the output shows `NULL` in the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `popen` to be able to read the output of a command. Make sure to close the stream with `pclose`.

```
FILE *f = popen("date", "r");
fgets(array, sizeof(array), f);
pclose(f);
```

But, you could use `localtime` and `strftime` instead of executing an external program.

```
time_t t = time(0);
struct tm lt;
localtime_r(&t, &lt);
strftime(array, sizeof(array), "%a %b %d &T %z %Y", &lt);
```

`ctime` is similar, but does not include the timezone.

```
ctime_r(&t, array);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `system(command)`, its return value is not a `char*` to the command's output, but an exit code of the command. The command completes successfully, and returns `0`; that's why you see a `NULL`. If you would like to fetch the string returned by the `"date"` command, you need to capture the output stream and convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t result;
    char array[25] = {'\0'};
    result = time(NULL);
    sprintf(array, "%s", asctime(localtime(&result)));
    printf("%s", array);
    return(0);
}
```